# What happens when 2 classes create objects of each other?

Tags: java

As far as I know when an object is created within a given class memory is allocated for that particular object. 
but in this case:

```
public class KindA {
    KindB b = new KindB();
    // rest of the code
}
```

```
public class KindB {
    KindA a = new KindA();
    // rest of the code
}
```

What happens in this case on the memory allocation side of things when 2 classes create objects of eachother?

Comment: The JVM manages it, why do you care?

Comment: But in this situation isn't there recursion? I wanted to know what exactly happens before I could code using this model.

Comment: A class can also have a reference to itself. The JVM manages it, as a Java developer you do not need to be concerned with explicit memory management (in fact, there **isn't** explicit memory management).

Comment: The constructor of the two classes will not terminate normally, eventually you will get an exception because the stack memory is full.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think he is asking how it works? Please clarify your answer in depth.

Comment: @Athiruban It was a comment, I'll try and create an answer; but it's (of necessity) a little complex.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's ok. I am also looking forward the answer for this.

Comment: I was wrong, in this example it results in a `StackOverflowError` if you try to instantiate `KindA` or `KindB` normally. The correct way to do this would use a `Builder` or `Factory` pattern, and then it should work.

Comment: It would be hard to compile this, due to the circular dependency. But to be honest, I have no idea why you would do this.

Comment: @Unihedron There is no problem with compiling. It compiles fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get a `StackOverflowError` if you try to initialize one of the classes, since the initializer of `KindA` creates a new object of type `KindB` and therefore the initializer of `KindB` runs, which creates a new object of type `KindA` and `KindA`'s initializer runs again, which creates and initializes a new object of type `KindB` and so on ...

This is a infinite recursion, therefore the stackoverflow.

Comment: Will this be the same case when I create a Stack (java.util class) of KindB objects in class KindA? (or vice-versa)

Comment: Is it a stack overflow? Not familiar with JVM memory management, but in C++ you'd allocate these objects from the heap and eventually run out of memory that way, rather than because you smashed the stack.

Comment: @KeshavSonni: If you create a `Stack` you don't automatically create an instance of the "element type". Therefore creating a `Stack<KindB>` in `KindA` would not cause a recursion (but keeping `KindB b = new KindB();` and not changing `KindB` does).